# How to hide my product and API from other developers in centralized shared Azure APIM service instance?

Tags: azure-api-management

We have a centralized development instance for Azure API Management Service where developers from different agencies/organization creates their Products, API and subscription. Essentially they have contributor role on resource group of APIM instance. This is a centralized shared APIM instance.

I can probably create a Custom RBAC role that allows me to edit only my API but not sure how to hide my own API and products from others.

Is there a way for developers to hide their Products and API entirely from other developers in Admin portal as well as in Developer portal?

Comment: I'm not sure that would work, but you could have custom role for each user group with read permissions assigned only to the products they need to see.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried implementing the restriction at the product level?

1. Check your user list.

[image]

2. Create a group with by selecting the required members.

[image]

3. Create an product( Add required APIs) -> Go to access control -> Add a group (you may remove the Administrator group)

[image]

Comment: How will it hide the API from other developers in Admin portal.?

Comment: Are you asking about the azure portal access here?

Comment: Yes, in the context of APIM, the admin portal is Azure portal

Comment: @Andy in that case you may check the standalone subscription https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-subscriptions#subscriptions-for-all-apis-or-an-individual-api - if this suffices the requirement

Comment: @Andy If the answer helped please accept the answer and up-vote so that it helps others in the community.